# Opening external .pptx and .xlsx once and running multiple subroutines on them

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I guess this is a easy one but since I'm very new in VBA I can't figure it out.

I have a code which was design to copy data from a third Excel spreadsheet and paste it into multiple charts of a Power Point presentation.

This peace of code above opens the Power Point presentation and the Excel spreadsheet. `dir_pptx` and `dir_xlsx` are the respective filepaths.

```
Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open("" & dir_pptx & "") 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=dir_xlsx
```

The point is that this process is divided in ~6 independent subs (and it has to be like this, I don't want to change it), so everytime I have to update the presentation I have to run `sub1`, save/close both `.pptx` and `.xlsx` files, run `sub2`, save/close, run `sub3`, save/close and so on, because otherwise `sub2` opens the files again and updated it, discarding the changes I already made in `sub1`.

My question: how to modify this code for first check if the files are already opened and 
1. If they aren't, open it;
2. If they are, don't open it again and procced the routine using them.

Answer (score 0):

These top level objects aren't maintained in a collection automatically (unlike, say, all Worksheet objects are in the collection Worksheets).

You can build and maintain your own collection of objects and use them later ...

(untested) expansion of your code snippet would look like this ...

```
Set myObjCol = New Collection

Set ObjPPT = Nothing
For Each myObj In myObjCol
    If myObj.Name = "Microsoft PowerPoint" Then 'Already have PPT 
        Set ObjPPT = myObj
        Exit For
    End If
Next myObj
If ObjPPT Is Nothing Then
    Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application") 'Create PPT
    myObjCol.Add ObjPPT
End If

Set ObjPresentation = Nothing
For Each myObj In myObjCol
    If myObj.Name = Filename Then 'The file is already open 
        Set ObjPresentation = myObj 
        Exit For
    End If
Next myObj
If ObjPresentation Is Nothing Then 'Open the file
    Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open(PathName & Filename)
    myObjCol.Add ObjPresentation
End If

'... other code
```

In other parts of the code, when the file is closed and the application is quit, you will need to use the `.Remove` method of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: (Warning: AirCode Ahead)

```
Function PresentationObject() as Object

Dim objPPTApp as object
Static objPresentation as Object

If objPresentation is Nothing then

Set objPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set objPresentation = ObjPPTApp.Presentations.Open("" & dir_pptx & "")

End if

Set PresentationObject = objPresentation

End Function
```

Then in use, call the function rather than referring directly to the object variable that contains the presentation.

Comment: Thank you @SteveRindsberg. It is quite like what I want, but unfortunately it doesn't work. When I ran sub 2 the pptx was opened again as a "only reading" file, jut like my current problem.

Comment: What syntax did you use with it?  Set objPresentation=PresentationObject in your main subroutine is what should work.

Comment: True, maybe I'm not catching something. This is what I'm doing: `Sub1`: 1.Your code + xlsx opener that I mention in my question 2. Procedures of copying/pasting activating both xlsx and pptx files by `Workbooks(xlsx_name).Sheets(1).Activate` `Set ObjSlide = ObjPresentation.Slides(slds(i))` 3. End sub. For the next subs the process is pretty much the same.

Comment: Rather than explaining what bits of code you've used, it'd be a lot simpler to follow if you'd post the actual code.